How to draw a interactive dynamic image with .Net MAUI Graphics
I want to create an interactive image (tree) in .NET MAUI (Graphics), where customers can hang their fruits on it. To realize this, I played with a grid view, but that didn't really work out.
My question is, how can I draw/build the tree below .NET MAUI Graphics (SkiaSharp) with a plus icon, which brings up a context menu,
I also want to be able to specify the number of fruits, which will be hung on a tree.


EDIT
The prototype code below has been tried but does not seem to work. For example, he does not redraw on a canvas.
<skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="skiaView"
                  WidthRequest="600"
                  HeightRequest="400"
                  EnableTouchEvents="True"
                  PaintSurface="OnPaintSurface"
                  Touch="OnTouch" />



private void OnPaintSurface(object sender, KPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{

    var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;
    canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

    // Draw the tree SVG
    canvas.DrawPicture(_treeSvg.Picture);

}

private void OnTouch(object sender, SKTouchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ActionType == SKTouchAction.Pressed)
    {
        // Check if the touch point intersects with any branching rectangle
        ShowContextMenu(e.Location);
    }
}

private void RenderSvgAtPoint(SKSvg svg, SKPoint location)
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        using (var surface = SKSurface.Create(new  SKImageInfo((int)skiaView.CanvasSize.Width, (int)skiaView.CanvasSize.Height)))
        {
            var canvas = surface.Canvas;

            //// Draw existing SVG
            canvas.DrawPicture(_treeSvg.Picture);

            // Draw new SVG at the selected location
            canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture, location.X, location.Y);
        }

        skiaView.InvalidateSurface();
    });
}

private async void ShowContextMenu(SKPoint location)
{
    var options = new string[] { "RENDER APPLE" };

    // Display context menu
    var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Choose an option", null, null, options);

    // Handle selected option
    if (action == options[0])
    {
        var newSvg = new SKSvg();
        using (var stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MauiApp1.Resources.Images.apple.svg"))
        {
            newSvg.Load(stream);
            RenderSvgAtPoint(newSvg, location);
        }
    }
}


“How to draw an interactive graphic is a reallly broad question.  Can you be more specific about where you are stuck or the particular problem you’re having?

@Jason More in the context of: How do you render something like this with canvas and, for example, add an "add button".
